# Safe to power a raspberry pi from a 50W adapter

Tags: power-supply

I have a power adapter that is rated at 50W (5V, 10A output), and I was wondering if it would be safe to run a single pi from it?

I am planning on using it for powering more in the future, but would it require 10 be connected (in parallel) to prevent damage?

Comment: How are planning to power more in the future?  Using a USB hub?

Comment: by using more wires

Comment: http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/221147000574?ssPageName=STRK:MEWNX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1497.l2649 is what I am using

Comment: Thanks for posting the item.  This is really what I would call a hard-wired power supply.  Also, to answer the 2nd part of your question, you will need to connect the multiple devices in parallel to keep the output voltage at 5V.  If you connected them in series ohm's law will cause the voltage to divide between the two devices depending on their resistance.  You should be fine connecting more than one device as long as you ensure you never exceed the power supplies 10A output current limitation.

Comment: One risk: 10A will be able to burn much fatter wires/components than a smaller supply if something goes wrong. Good short circuit protection helps, though, but that depends on the psu.

Comment: @XTL Absolutely, that would be a pain. If I wired them up in parallel (for only 4), straight from the supply directly, would each pair have to handle 2.5 amps, or only for the amount being drawn through?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

50 watts is the maximum power the supply is capable of providing.  RPi will take only what it requires from the power supply. As long as the **voltage** is 5 volts and the supply is capable of providing the **current** RPi requires (.700 amp) you're OK.  So your power supply is OK to use with a single RPi.

Comment: To clarify, it will work fine as long as you are using a *regulated* supply. An unregulated supply will likely put out significantly more than 5V unless it's loaded to near its current rating (10A in this case). If you put a voltmeter on the supply (with nothing else connected) and power it on, and see ~5V, it's a regulated supply.

Answer (score 9):

Some switching supplies need a minimum load to get good regulation. It probably won't damage the RPi, but you should confirm that the voltage is 5V without too much ripple if you can.